# Why does my neural network perform better with more input neurons than features/variables?

Tags: performance, matlab, input, neural-network, layer

Why does my neural network perform better with more input neurons than features/variables? Now if I use the exact input neurons to features/variables the neural network performs much worse. For example, I have 6 dimensions of data that are 200 in length (or 200 samples). Within that data there are groups of 6 data sets - is this why my NN with 36 neuron inputs performs better than 6 neuron inputs? The dimensions should suggest I just need a NN with 6 input neurons. The hidden layers for the 6 inputs are 12 and 6 and for the 36 inputs, are 72 and 36 respectively.
It's been a long time since I last used NNs and so many thanks for answers or pointers on this?

Comment: How do you feed 6 inputs to 36 neurons?

Comment: %[R,Q] = size(P); S1 = 36; S2 = 54; S3 = 54; [S4,Q] = size(T);
net = newff(minmax(P),[S1 S2 S3 S4],{ 'tansig' 'tansig' 'tansig' 'tansig' 'purelin'},'trainrp','learnk','mse');  Using the following code and where P = 6*200 and T = 1*200. The NN works and the NN with S1 = 36 performs much better than the NN works with S1 = 6.

Comment: Don't worry about this question unlike my PhD and Post Doc years I am dancing in and out of ML and just realised the following code:
%net = newff(minmax(P),[S1 S2 S3 S4],{'tansig' 'tansig' 'tansig' 'purelin'},'traingdx','learnk','mse'); ......... has the input layer set to minmax(P) and not S1 ........basically I have a very bloated DNN ! I was wondering why couldn't find anything on this subject ! I am not going mad !  ........Thank you for the nudge as I started to really check the code I had used many times in the past.